# Is this the right behaviour of ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a country select list. I want the selected to be Germany (ID: 2).

When I select a value, the model saves the ID, not the whole object.

```
    $scope.countries = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Italy' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Spain' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Germany' },
        { id: 4, name: 'France' }
    ];

    // DESIRED BEHAVIOUR
    $scope.selectedCountry = 3; // GERMANY ID
```

This fiddle indicates what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgevdx1m/

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the `track by` with ng-options, it's probably a bug.

if you remove track by, the ng-options works as expected
if you change it to `track by $index` then the wrong element is selected (France) as it's index in array is 3

and any `track by country*` doesn't work at all

Comment: The problem is If I don't use the "track by", option value will be "number:1" and in some cases like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543278/issues-with-location-search-and-select-ng-options I don't need that...

Comment: Don't bother with the generated DOM, what you should be concerned is the `model` you assign to select

Comment: I mean, if model's inital value is "1" (string), and the select option is 1 (integer), it won't select the option at the beginning!

Comment: Obviously that will not work as it's not the same value and type

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, using "track by" does not compare the values (that's what I need), but it won't select the initial value neither
http://jsfiddle.net/3qedozzv/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94343/discussion-between-maurycy-and-ulrira).

Answer (score -1):

Well, Germany is the ID: 3

```
    // THIS WORKS, BUT THE INITIAL MODEL WOULD BE THE OBJECT
    //$scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries[2];
    //$scope.selectedCountry = { id: 3, name: 'Germany' };
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this way `ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries track by country.id"`. Angular takes id by itself and write it in option's value.